# What are the advantages of jQuery Ajax vs UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I saw couple of similar question here on StackOverFlow but **none** of them to summarize with the following criteria.

What are the advantages of jquery.ajax vs UpdatePanel (like - viewstate, speed, size)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, comparing jquery ajax to update panel is a bit like comparing apples vs oranges.

UpdatePanel is very easy to use; you really don't have to write any significant code to achieve AJAX, works seamlessly with server controls model. This is achieved by issuing asynchronous post request - so all form elements get posted including view-state. On server side, entire control tree gets loaded and page follows normal life cycle till rendering at which only html from update panel is sent (along with view-state) to client side. So you have large request size, more server load and large response size.

Alternative is to make async server calls, where request would carry only data that is needed for server call. The server would respond with the data needed. Typically, one would use JSON to transfer data to/from server, reducing request and response size. On server side, typically, a script service or page method is used which will do the specific task (as opposed to following a page life cycle) reducing server load.

Now, script services/page methods can be either invoked using proxies generated by ScriptManager or using jquery AJAX. I prefer jquery to avoid the larger size of proxy code generated by ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

For me the biggest disadvantage of the UpdatePanel is the generated HTML output. Just give it a try and have a look at your HTML I think it isn't as readable and small as it could be.

On the other site the entire Microsoft Ajax Lib has been discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

The drawbacks of Update panel is [Why ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels are dangerous](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)