# asp update panel and JSON with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, updatepanel

i have a qeustion on  design decision

i have a aspx webform that has two dropdownlist

one of them are set to autopostback in order to generate values in the second dropdownlist.

my lecturer told me that i can use json with ajax to improve the postback.

however i googled online and come across the asp updatepanel function.

i want to ask , does the two works like the same ? if i have to use json with ajax, do i have to write the page in traditional html instead of html with asp controls ?

what are the pros and cons to this two ?

Thanks,

WuSen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link [What are the advantages of jQuery Ajax vs UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907900/what-are-the-advantages-of-jquery-ajax-vs-updatepanel) or even you can find more here http://codingstill.com/2012/02/asp-net-and-ajax-all-about-update-panels-web-methods-page-methods-and-jquery/

Comment: after reading the link above , i am thinking that updatepanel is not the best options,here is another question , if i use json with ajax to do the postback, do i have to convert my asp html to html without asp controls? i mean a filename .html instead of a file with .aspx

Comment: why doing a postback or why you want that? with ajax you can avoid it and it will increase the page performance as well. Html controls are very much faster than a asp server control so if you want better performance from your page so you have to change them.

Comment: thanks man you have answered my doubts,the autopostback is because i was using 2 asp dropdownlist , and the first dropdownlist is autopostback, so that the second dropdownlist knows what to display.

Comment: There are server side controls so to populate data postback is required but if you do this with ajax and jquery it will pretty much fast and no need of any kind of postback..

Comment: i am going to learn ajax and jquery now , i am new to programming basically